# Event delegation on non nested elements

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-5, event-delegation

I'm using Bootstrap group radio button on which I would like to write event delegation.

```
<div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="Basic radio toggle button group">
  <input type="radio" class="btn-check" name="btnradio" id="btnradio1" autocomplete="off" checked>
  <label class="btn btn-outline-primary" for="btnradio1">Radio 1</label>

  <input type="radio" class="btn-check" name="btnradio" id="btnradio2" autocomplete="off">
  <label class="btn btn-outline-primary" for="btnradio2">Radio 2</label>

  <input type="radio" class="btn-check" name="btnradio" id="btnradio3" autocomplete="off">
  <label class="btn btn-outline-primary" for="btnradio3">Radio 3</label>
</div>
```

Since the labels are not nested in the button, the following is not returning the inputs.

```
event.target.closest('.btn-check');
```

Is there a proper way to write event delegation on this type of non-nested elements?

Comment: What event are you listening to? If a "click" one, the click events on the <label> elements will be redispatched on the linked <input> anyway.

Comment: @Kalido, yes, but I had an event.preventDefault(), to prevent the event to propagate to parents of the parents of the btn-group. I'm searching how to solve this issue ...

Comment: Then please ask about that issue. Show the actual code you're having problem with.

Comment: @Kaiido Yes, but I didn't understood that was the real issue, so from now I should be able to solve it by myself.

Comment: But... StackOverflow isn't a "fix-my-code" service, we aim at building a repository of good question & answers. Here your question isn't good, because it asks about an nonexistent problem, and thus it received poor answers that don't solve nothing and even show solutions to the linked theme of "event delegation" that are less optimal than your original solution. So please, [edit] your question so that it's about the actual issue, you can even post a self answer if you wish.

Comment: It would help if you posted a [mcve] so we could see other issues too

Comment: Guys, these moral lessons on SO are, in my opinion, rather unwelcome. Every week, I see closed questions on SO that have hundreds, if not thousands, of upvotes. Let's give it a few years and see if my question was really that useless!

Comment: The morale here is that you had an X/Y problem and anyone else reading your question might think that that was the actual problem. Also as you saw, I now engaged in a useless discussion with Kalido since we were both correct. closest WOULD work - that closest is unnecessary on your code because you do not have nested elements, does not change that closest will return the element itself if it matches the selector.

Comment: I understand your point of view, and you are right. But you'll also have to understand that when I initially posted the question I didn't see it was an X/Y problem. If I had understood this I would not have asked my question. I can't post my full code with dozens of files and thousands of lines. I try to post the minimal reproductible example. But sometime, I underestimate the true origin of the problem. Anyway, thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how. Clicking the radio OR the label will show the ID.
No need for `closest` here, but closest WILL return the element itself if it matches the selector

In Bootstrap it also works

```js
document.querySelector('.btn-group').addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  const tgt = e.target;
  if (tgt.matches('.btn-check')) console.log(tgt.id)
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rbsA2VBKQhggwzxH7pPCaAqO46MgnOM80zW1RWuH61DGLwZJEdK2Kadq2F9CUG65" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="Basic radio toggle button group">
  <input type="radio" class="btn-check" name="btnradio" id="btnradio1" autocomplete="off" checked>
  <label class="btn btn-outline-primary" for="btnradio1">Radio 1</label>

  <input type="radio" class="btn-check" name="btnradio" id="btnradio2" autocomplete="off">
  <label class="btn btn-outline-primary" for="btnradio2">Radio 2</label>

  <input type="radio" class="btn-check" name="btnradio" id="btnradio3" autocomplete="off">
  <label class="btn btn-outline-primary" for="btnradio3">Radio 3</label>
</div>
```

If you have buttons with child elements, you DO need `closest`

Clicking the button text OR the icon will show the ID

```js
document.querySelector('.btn-group').addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  const tgt = e.target.closest('.btn'); // would not work on the icon without closest
  if (tgt) console.log(tgt.id)
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rbsA2VBKQhggwzxH7pPCaAqO46MgnOM80zW1RWuH61DGLwZJEdK2Kadq2F9CUG65" crossorigin="anonymous">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.4.2/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-z3gLpd7yknf1YoNbCzqRKc4qyor8gaKU1qmn+CShxbuBusANI9QpRohGBreCFkKxLhei6S9CQXFEbbKuqLg0DA==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />

<div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="Basic button group">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary"  id="btn1">Text</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary"  id="btn2" ><i class="fa fa-exclamation-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
</div>
```

Comment: `closest()` would work just the same (actually better) if used like that. What makes you think you solved OP's issue, whatever it is?

Comment: I didn't understood why your code was working and not mine. The fact is I have a e.preventDefault() in my callback function. That was my real issue.  Thx

Comment: @Kaiido Closest what to what? Why would closest work better? We do not have a nested element here at all. I would use closest in a button situation where the closest would handle child elements of the button

Comment: See my second example of when closest IS needed

Comment: @Kaiido Ok, I now see what you mean. Closest SHOULD work too. There is no need for it but it should work. So the issue was something else that OP now has revealed.

Answer (score 1):

In this code, i use the event delegation technique to listen for click events on the parent container with the class `btn-group`.
When a click event occurs, we check if the clicked element is an `<input>` element with the type *"radio"*, and if so, we log its **ID** to the *console*

```js
  document.querySelector('.btn-group').addEventListener('click', (event) => {
    if (event.target.tagName === 'INPUT' && event.target.type === 'radio') {
      console.log(event.target.id);
    }
  });
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rbsA2VBKQhggwzxH7pPCaAqO46MgnOM80zW1RWuH61DGLwZJEdK2Kadq2F9CUG65" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="Basic radio toggle button group">
  <input type="radio" class="btn-check" name="btnradio" id="btnradio1" autocomplete="off" checked>
  <label class="btn btn-outline-primary" for="btnradio1">Radio 1</label>

  <input type="radio" class="btn-check" name="btnradio" id="btnradio2" autocomplete="off">
  <label class="btn btn-outline-primary" for="btnradio2">Radio 2</label>

  <input type="radio" class="btn-check" name="btnradio" id="btnradio3" autocomplete="off">
  <label class="btn btn-outline-primary" for="btnradio3">Radio 3</label>
</div>
```